# sql server select attribute but not group by that attribute

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions

I am working on a query to count the number of results for a given month and year. However, I also need to use the full date to create a month year string. I am aware  that anything that is in the select clause must also be in the group by clause. However, I only want to group by the month and year to get the correct count results. How can I resolve this?

```
SELECT category, Count(ID), MONTH(aDate) AS month , YEAR(aDate) AS year, aDate,
CONVERT(CHAR(4),aDate) , 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),aDate) , 120) as monthYear
FROM table
GROUP BY month, year, category
```

Comment: Confused, there should be no difference between grouping by Month,Year, Category and Month,Year,MonthYear,Category

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the entire date, just use the convert statement as a part of your group by clause

```
     SELECT category, 
        Count(ID), 
        MONTH(aDate) AS [month] , 
        YEAR(aDate) AS [year], 
        CONVERT(CHAR(4),aDate) , 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),aDate) , 120) as monthYear 
FROM table 
GROUP BY MONTH(aDate), 
        YEAR(aDate), 
        category,
        CONVERT(CHAR(4),aDate) , 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),aDate) , 120)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(category), Count(ID), MONTH(aDate) AS month , YEAR(aDate) AS year, MAX(aDate),
CONVERT(CHAR(4),MAX(aDate)) , 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),MAX(aDate)) , 120) as monthYear
FROM table
GROUP BY MONTH(aDate), YEAR(aDate)
```

Comment: Rather than just posting code, you should explain _why_ you made the changes that you made.